# Prove circle packing solution is optimal

Tags: optimization

**Background:**
This is a follow on from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938487/how-to-maximize-area-of-two-circles-inside-a-rectangle-without-overlapping/938534#938534) of how to maximise the area of two non overlapping circles of arbitrary radii packed into a rectangle of arbitrary width and height. I proposed a solution based on greedy selection of the first circle, then the second:

[image: Two circles in a rectangle]

With a solution of:
$$r_1 = (\frac{h}{2})$$
$$r_2=(-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{w}\sqrt{h}+w+\frac{h}{2})$$

**Question: How do I prove that this is the optimal solution?**

Its seems intuitive that when $w=h$ or $w=2h$ this will be optimal. My concern is that somewhere in between there may be a better arrangement.

I am having difficulty setting up the equations to show that for any point in between the rate of change of area of the first circle as $r_1$ **decreases** is greater than the rate of change as $r_2$ **increases**, which I *hope* would prove this. Help is appreciated.